# How can I stop automatic pop-ups of live tiles in Window 8?

Tags: windows-8, live-tiles

I am using windows 8. Kindly someone suggest me how to stop automatic pop-ups of live store tiles. It pop-ups automatically every time which frustrates me, I can't focus on my work, I have to remove it every time. I disabled its update option, but still it's poping up.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click a live tile that disturbs you, and select "Turn Live Tile Off". That should make the tile static. Similarly, you can turn it on later, if you want.

If there are tiles you don't need, you can just remove them from your Start screen. This will NOT remove the app, just the tile.